# convulotion associative between vectors

Tags: matrices

We learnt that convolution is commutative, meaning that:

$$xh = hx.$$

However if I take:

$$h=[-1,0,1] \mbox{ and } x=[1,1,1]^T $$

($T$ is transpose)

I get that $xh$ is not equal to $hx$.

Could someone explain this please?

Many thanks.

Comment: Actually, $x*h=h*x$ means that the binary operation $*$ is **commutative**. Note that $*$ is associative iff $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$ for any $a,b,c$.

Comment: thanks for fix...can you help me solve this problem? thanks alot

Comment: Why do you take the transpose?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing image processing? In some image processing literature, convolution is defined differently and it may be non-commutative.

With zero-based indexing, the convolution of two vectors $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^N$ is usually defined by
$$
(u\ast v)_i=\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty u_j\,v_{i-j}
$$
(where $u_j\ v_{i-j}=0$ if either index is out of bound). With this definition, convolution is commutative and in your case, we have $x\ast h=h\ast x=[-1,-1,0,1,1]$.

In some (but not all) image processing literature, convolution is defined in a manner like this:
$$
(u\ast v)_{N+i}=\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty u_{i+j}\,v_j.
$$
With this definition, convolution is not commutative (in your case, $h\ast x=[-1,-1,0,1,1]$ but $x\ast h=[1,1,0,-1,-1]$). When convolution is defined this way, the authors usually simply want to apply a symmetric filter $v$ to the pixels $u$ (and out-of-bound pixels may be zeroed out, replaced by the leftmost or rightmost pixel, or indexed using modulo arithmetic, depending on situations) and there is no need to consider $v\ast u$ in the first place. So, whether convolution is commutative is irrelevant.